# How to update menu item in android

Tags: android

I have an activity with menu items. Every time when user come to this activity, i want to update the value of textView with some Utility value. This is my code.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    RelativeLayout badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.badge).getActionView();
    TextView tv = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textview);
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(Utility.ShoppingCartItemCount()));
    return true;
}
```

This is updating the value only once (when launching activity). But when user moves from this activity and come on this activity again, this is not getting updated even value for Utility.ShoppingCartItemCount() is updated.

How to solve this?

Comment: what does `Utility.ShoppingCartItemCount())` returns? Does it provide you different value every time? Because, it is sure that `onPrepareOptionsMenu` will be called, when Menu is shown every time. so if you are not seeing updated text, that must be the method you should check

Comment: @Devesh check `Utility.ShoppingCartItemCount()` persists when you come back to your main activity. If so then change text of `TextView` in `onResume` method of activity..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [invalidateOptionsMenu()](https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu())

This will be call onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) again.

**edit**)

I have some code like below

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (currentPage == 8) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_p, menu);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.purchaseRestore:
            // TODO: Restore purchase
            return true;
        case R.id.purchaseTerm:
            // TODO: Show Term by WebView
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

When my user click other button, put invalidateOptionsMenu() after currentPage = 8 in Button's OnClickListener. In result, User can show Option Menu.

**edit**))

invalidateOptionsMenu() will **force** reload onCreateOptionsMenu and onPrepareOptionsMenu.

If this methods doesn't working for you, try to debug Utility.ShoppingCartItemCount().

Comment: did you tried it yourself? did it worked? you may want to post your working code as a Answer, so that OP can validate. Otherwise, your current post is not much useful as answer, and more of a comment.

Comment: Yeah, i try that code in my project. i'll add more working code on it.